# How can I make this layout for android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

[SOLVED]I have a very specific layout that I want to make. It feels like it should be very easy to create but I can't seem to wrap my fingers around it. So I want to create a layout that looks like the image below. How the hell do I get this? I just get the text and the 2 images and then get the buttons to be visible. Posted my layout below as well.

Thanks in advance // eXpliCo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKGX7.jpg

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/question_text"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/question_text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/picture_placeholder" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/picture_placeholder" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vote_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vote_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vote_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: I got a solution now. I don't know if it's the best but it works for me. But I can't answer my own code yet so I'll just post my solution here.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test123 312 123 312"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Test" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Test" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the current result with this code?

Comment: I think you should try this with `RelativeLayout` instead, use the child layouts as it is if they work and set the image one to `android:layout_above="+@id/vote_layout"`

Answer (score 2):

In your second `LinearLayout`, set the `orientation` to `horizontal`.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to work. What LinearLayout do you mean? The one with Images or the first set of buttons?

Comment: `orientation` is `horizontal` by default, no need to set it.

Comment: The one that wraps your ImageView, that will make your two images be in a row. I thought this was your issue as you didn't detail what's really wrong with the code you posted. If you meant putting a separation between your buttons within a row, you might use the `margin` or `marginLeft` and `marginRight` properties.

Comment: Well the thing is that my problem is that the image layout overwrites the two bottom layouts (the once with the buttons). The two bottom layout are 0 in height and they are hidden below the gui at the bottom. I need the two bottom layouts to get the height of a button and push the image layout up :) Its hard to explain :/ :(

Comment: Try setting the `layout_width` property of your very first `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`

Comment: This will depend on your image size.  it works fine with smaller images but you're saying that your images are pushing the button layouts off the screen.  You may have to enforce a fixed height and/or aspect ratio depending on how dynamic the images are here.

Comment: if your app is doing something like comparing pictures or the actual image content is the driving force behind its purpose, you might consider a different layout for the buttons.  For instance, maybe the button function can be put in the actionbar or in a transparent toolbar overlay

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:text="Some Text here"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SomeText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SomeText"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_weight="1" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vote_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vote_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_layout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vote_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vote_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this works with smaller images but not larger images. If this is the case then use `layout_weight` in each child `LinearLayout` so that each takes up a certain amount of space. This will help the `layout` to look similar on different screen sizes and resolutions.

So, for instance...

```
<TextView 
    android:text="Some Text here"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ...
LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    ...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout1"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    ...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout2"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    ...
```

You may have to adjust the `weights` to what you want/need but something like that should help. You will also want to set your `height` for each of those to `0dp` since the parent `LinearLayout` is vertical.